# Go and Fyne - Need response from dialog and enable/disable Submit button

Tags: go, dialog, fyne

Just starting to look at both Go and Fyne. After writing a test CRUD program using information obtained from examples, I need to solve the following:

1. I need an initial Dialog or similar in order to allow selection of an existing record or "new" to indicate a new record. My existing Dialog does not handle this adequately.
2. I need to be able to enable/disable the Submit button to allow or disallow update if the data has has-not changed.
3. The program compiles without error, however "go vet" and VsCode indicates (eg. for line):

```
     {"Given Names:", arwWidgets[I_NDX_GIVEN]},
```

```
 go vet shows:
 ERROR:  "unknown field 'Key' in struct literal of type widget.FormItem",
 however, if I include a key, compiler fails.
```

4. Being new to both Go and Fyne, there are probably fundamental mistakes.

Test program is as follows:

```
package main
// Dependency: local directory "data".
import (
    "errors"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "fyne.io/fyne"
    "fyne.io/fyne/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/dialog"
    "fyne.io/fyne/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/widget"
)

const BY_SEP byte = byte('|')
const I_ARRAY_LEN int = 10
const I_NDX_GIVEN int = 0
const I_NDX_FAMILY int = 1
const I_NDX_TITLE int = 2
const I_NDX_ADDR1 int = 3
const I_NDX_ADDR2 int = 4
const I_NDX_ADDR3 int = 5
const I_NDX_STATE int = 6
const I_NDX_ZIP int = 7
const I_NDX_TELE1 int = 8
const I_NDX_TELE2 int = 9

var _arsOldData [I_ARRAY_LEN]string
var _arsNewData [I_ARRAY_LEN]string
var _tfDataHasChanged bool
var _sKey string
var _arwEntryWidgets [I_ARRAY_LEN]*widget.Entry
var _wApp fyne.App
var _wWindow fyne.Window
var _wModal widget.PopUp
var _wFormKeyEntry widget.Form

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func main() {
    log.Println("In fytest01")
    _, err := os.Stat("./data/")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("You need to create directory: 'data'")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    //fnReadData()
    _wApp := app.New()
    _wWindow := _wApp.NewWindow("Customer Details")
    //_wFormKeyEntry := fnCreateKeyForm()
    wFormMain := fnCreateMainForm()
    //_wModal := widget.NewModalPopUp(_wFormKeyEntry, _wWindow.Canvas())
    _wWindow.Resize(fyne.NewSize(500, 400))
    _wWindow.CenterOnScreen()
    _wWindow.SetContent(widget.NewVBox(
        wFormMain,
        widget.NewGroup("",
            fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewGridLayout(2),
                widget.NewButton("Exit", func() {
                    _wApp.Quit()
                }),
                widget.NewButton("Submit", func() {
                    log.Println("Submit button pressed")
                    err := fnUpdateData()
                    if err == nil {
                        dialog.ShowInformation("Information", "Data was updated", _wWindow)
                        wEntryForKey := widget.NewEntry()
                        wEntryForKey.SetPlaceHolder("Enter Key (4) : ")
                        wEntryForKey.OnChanged = func(sKey string) {
                            log.Println("Entered", sKey)
                            if len(sKey) == 4 {
                                _sKey = sKey
                            }
                            if len(_sKey) == 4 {
                                dialog.ShowInformation("Information", "Key "+_sKey+" has been entered - press OK", _wWindow)
                                fnReadData()
                                fnRefreshWidgetData()
                            }
                        }
                        dialog.ShowCustom("Enter Customer Key", "OK", wEntryForKey, _wWindow)
                    } else {
                        dialog.ShowError(err, _wWindow)
                    }
                }),
            ))),
    )
    //fnShowKeyEntryDialog()

    wEntryForKey := widget.NewEntry()
    wEntryForKey.SetPlaceHolder("Enter Key (4) : ")
    wEntryForKey.OnChanged = func(sKey string) {
        log.Println("Entered", sKey)
        if len(sKey) == 4 {
            _sKey = sKey
        }
        if len(_sKey) == 4 {
            dialog.ShowInformation("Information", "Key "+_sKey+" has been entered - press OK", _wWindow)
            fnReadData()
            fnRefreshWidgetData()
        }
    }
    dialog.ShowCustom("Enter Customer Key", "OK", wEntryForKey, _wWindow)
    _wWindow.ShowAndRun()
    //_wModal.Show()
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func fnCreateAllEntryWidgets() {
    _arwEntryWidgets[I_NDX_GIVEN] = fnCreateSingleEntryWidget(I_NDX_GIVEN)
    _arwEntryWidgets[I_NDX_FAMILY] = fnCreateSingleEntryWidget(I_NDX_FAMILY)
    _arwEntryWidgets[I_NDX_TITLE] = fnCreateSingleEntryWidget(I_NDX_TITLE)
    _arwEntryWidgets[I_NDX_ADDR1] = fnCreateSingleEntryWidget(I_NDX_ADDR1)
    _arwEntryWidgets[I_NDX_ADDR2] = fnCreateSingleEntryWidget(I_NDX_ADDR2)
    _arwEntryWidgets[I_NDX_ADDR3] = fnCreateSingleEntryWidget(I_NDX_ADDR3)
    _arwEntryWidgets[I_NDX_STATE] = fnCreateSingleEntryWidget(I_NDX_STATE)
    _arwEntryWidgets[I_NDX_ZIP] = fnCreateSingleEntryWidget(I_NDX_ZIP)
    _arwEntryWidgets[I_NDX_TELE1] = fnCreateSingleEntryWidget(I_NDX_TELE1)
    _arwEntryWidgets[I_NDX_TELE2] = fnCreateSingleEntryWidget(I_NDX_TELE2)
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func fnCreateSingleEntryWidget(iNdxData int) *widget.Entry {
    wEntry := widget.NewEntry()
    wEntry.SetText(_arsOldData[iNdxData])
    wEntry.OnChanged = func(sText string) {
        _arsNewData[iNdxData] = sText
        fnCheckIfDataHasChanged()
    }
    return wEntry
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func fnCreateFormFields(arwWidgets [I_ARRAY_LEN]*widget.Entry) []*widget.FormItem {
    return []*widget.FormItem{
        {"Given Names:", arwWidgets[I_NDX_GIVEN]},
        {"Family Name: ", arwWidgets[I_NDX_FAMILY]},
        {"Title: ", arwWidgets[I_NDX_TITLE]},
        {"Address Ln 1: ", arwWidgets[I_NDX_ADDR1]},
        {"   ''   Ln 2: ", arwWidgets[I_NDX_ADDR2]},
        {"   ''   Ln 3: ", arwWidgets[I_NDX_ADDR3]},
        {"   ''   State ", arwWidgets[I_NDX_STATE]},
        {"   ''   Zip: ", arwWidgets[I_NDX_ZIP]},
        {"Telephone 1: ", arwWidgets[I_NDX_TELE1]},
        {"Telephone 2: ", arwWidgets[I_NDX_TELE2]},
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func fnCheckIfDataHasChanged() {
    var tfChanged bool = false
    for iNdxData := 0; !tfChanged && iNdxData < len(_arsOldData); iNdxData++ {
        tfChanged = (_arsNewData[iNdxData] != _arsOldData[iNdxData])
    }
    if tfChanged != _tfDataHasChanged {
        _tfDataHasChanged = tfChanged
        if tfChanged {
            //  COULD NOT CREATE _wBtnSubmitMain AS A GLOBAL VARIABLE.
            //_wBtnSubmitMain.Show()
            //_wBtnSubmitMain.Enable()
        } else {
            //_wBtnSubmitMain.Disable()
            //_wBtnSubmitMain.Hide()
        }
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func fnReadData() {
    _tfDataHasChanged = false
    log.Println("fnReadData: Key = " + _sKey)
    var sData string
    if len(_sKey) > 0 {
        arbData, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("./data/" + _sKey)
        if arbData != nil {
            sData = string(arbData)
        }
    }
    log.Println("fnReadData: sData = " + sData)

    /* CLEAR OLD DATA */
    for iNdxData := 0; iNdxData < I_ARRAY_LEN; iNdxData++ {
        _arsOldData[iNdxData] = ""
    }

    /* POPULATE DATA IF ANY */
    var iNdx1 int = 0
    var iNdxData int = 0
    var iLen int = len(sData)
    for iNdx2 := 0; iNdx2 < len(sData); iNdx2++ {
        if sData[iNdx2] == BY_SEP {
            _arsOldData[iNdxData] = sData[iNdx1:iNdx2]
            iNdx1 = iNdx2 + 1
            iNdxData++
        } else if iNdx2 == (iLen - 1) {
            _arsOldData[iNdxData] = sData[iNdx1 : iNdx2+1]
        }
    }
    for iNdx := 0; iNdx < I_ARRAY_LEN; iNdx++ {
        _arsNewData[iNdx] = _arsOldData[iNdx]
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func fnUpdateData() error {
    if !_tfDataHasChanged {
        return errors.New("Data has not changed")
    }

    if len(_sKey) < 1 {
        _sKey = "9999"
        //dialog.ShowInformation("Information", "Default key of 9999 was used", _wWindow)  // CAUSES ERROR
    }

    var sNewData string = ""
    for iNdxData, sVal := range _arsNewData {
        if strings.Index(sVal, "|") >= 0 {
            sVal = strings.ReplaceAll(sVal, "|", ":")
        }
        if iNdxData != I_ARRAY_LEN-1 {
            sNewData += sVal + string(BY_SEP)
        } else {
            sNewData += sVal
        }
    }
    log.Println("New Data = " + sNewData)
    var err error = ioutil.WriteFile("./data/"+_sKey, []byte(sNewData), 0644)
    if err == nil {
        for iNdxData := 0; iNdxData < len(_arsNewData); iNdxData++ {
            _arsOldData[iNdxData] = _arsNewData[iNdxData]
        }
        fnCheckIfDataHasChanged()
    }
    return err
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func fnCreateKeyForm() *widget.Form {
    wEntryKey := widget.NewEntry()
    return &widget.Form{
        Items: []*widget.FormItem{
            {"Key:", wEntryKey}},
        OnSubmit: func() {
            _sKey = wEntryKey.Text
            log.Println("Key = " + _sKey)
            fnReadData()
            log.Println("Data has been read")
            fnRefreshWidgetData()
            _wFormKeyEntry.Hide()
            //_wModal.Hide()
        },
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//func fnCreateMainWindow() {
//  log.Println("Creating Main Window   Form")
//  wFormMain := fnCreateMainForm()
//  log.Println("Creating Main Window   Window")
//  _wWindow.SetContent( //widget.NewVBox(
//      wFormMain,
//  )
//}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func fnCreateMainForm() *widget.Form {
    log.Println("Create form1 widgets")
    fnCreateAllEntryWidgets()
    log.Println("Create form1 FormFields")
    arwFormFields := fnCreateFormFields(_arwEntryWidgets)
    log.Println("Creating Form1")
    return &widget.Form{
        Items: arwFormFields,
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func fnRefreshWidgetData() {
    for iNdx := 0; iNdx < I_ARRAY_LEN; iNdx++ {
        _arwEntryWidgets[iNdx].SetText(_arsNewData[iNdx])
    }
}
```

Comment: Watch out, some global variables are declared but not set, the `_wApp := app.New()` creates a new variable in the scope of `main()`. If you wanted to set the global variable then use `_wApp = app.New()`.

Answer (score 1):

To change button options on toggle you need to use something like this:

```
buttonTitle := "Disable"
button := widget.NewButton(buttonTitle, nil)
changeButton := func() {
    // here could be your logic
    // how to disable/enable button
    if button.Text == "Disable" {
        buttonTitle = "Enable"
        //button.Disable()
    }
    button.SetText(buttonTitle)
    button.Refresh()
}
button.OnTapped = changeButton
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you just add a "New" button to the start window which fills in defaults then opens the main window.  Does that make sense?
2. You create the Submit button by creating and passing it directly to `SetContent`.  You need to save it in a variable, so that you can at some point call `Disable()` on it.

```
submitButton := widget.NewButton("Submit", func() {
    log.Println("Submit button pressed")
...
})
_wWindow.SetContent(widget.NewVBox(
    wFormMain,
    widget.NewGroup("",
        fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewGridLayout(2),
            widget.NewButton("Exit", func() {
                _wApp.Quit()
            }),
            submitButton,
        ))),
)

...
if dataChanged {
    submitButton.Enable()
} else {
    submitButton.Disable()
}
```

3. I think the `go vet` message is saying you should name all the fields in your struct literal (though I get a different message to you using Go 1.13).  Go allows you to add the values by order or by name - `go vet` is telling you that by name is safer (eg if fields are moved or inserted to the `FormItem` struct then your code would be broken).

Ie:

```
    return []*widget.FormItem{
        { Text: "Given Names:", Widget: arwWidgets[I_NDX_GIVEN]},
...
```

4. Also it may simplify things to put all your global variables into a struct and then you can have "methods" on the struct.  (There are a few reasons to avoid globals which you probably already know. I appreciate that this probably started as a simple test that has grown but it may be a good time to refactor.)

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I'll try that first chance I get. 90% of my time on this was trying to solve the problems stated. This is a common pattern, and an example is probably worthwhile. My first Go program, so just concentrating on getting something to work at this early stage.